# Home ZFS based NAS...What processor/chipset to use?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, raid, nas, zfs

So, I'm building a home/personal NAS. My plan is to expose both SMB fileshares for sharing files/media between hosts, but also to carve an iSCSI target LUN out of it for use by VMWare as a datastore. I want to use ZFS (software RAID) so that means I'll either be using FreeNAS, Solaris Express, or OpenIndiana.

My question is basically: How much horsepower do I need? Obviously I/O is going to be my bottleneck but I want to be sure that I am not limiting my I/O because of a slow processor or chipset.

So far the hardware plan is to use an Intel i3 and motherboard with one of the H87, Q87, or Z87 chipsets, a SAS controller (JBOD, no RAID) and if budget allows, I'm also hoping to get an SSD for the ZFS L2ARC and ZIL.

Does anyone think I could get away with an Intel Atom or cheaper/less-capable processor/chipset than the i3 and [HQZ]87 listed above?

Answer (score 1):

For small-scale NAS amount of memory is more important than CPU power for ZFS, IMHO. Almost any x86 CPU  on the market would do the job performance-wise, though some CPUs are better than others.

You do want CPU that supports 64-bit mode. That rules out older Atoms.

I would also recommend investing in a server board that supports ECC memory. ZFS's ability to validate data consistency on the disk if not worth a damn if your memory is bad (and it happens) and causes your OS to write garbage to disk.

i3 (or, even better, xeon e3-12xx v2/v3) should be more than sufficient. If you want to save few bucks, get Pentium [G21xx or one of its siblings](http://ark.intel.com/products/series/71075)  (and, surprisingly, they *do* support ECC memory, too) or [a celeron that supports ECC](http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced/?s=t&FamilyText=Intel%C2%AE%20Celeron%C2%AE%20Processor&ECCMemory=true).

SSD for L2 ARC is very nice to have, but keep in mind that your RAM needs to scale up with L2 ARC size. Rough rule of thumb is ~ 1GB of RAM for each 10G of L2 ARC. Considering that memory is quite affordable these days, I would go with 8GB as a minimum.

As for SAS controllers, LSI SAS/SATA controllers seem to be well supported by almost everyone, be it Windows, Linux, FreeBSD or solaris variants. You can get rebranded ones pretty cheaply (google "IBM M1015" -- it's rebadged LSI 9220-8i), flash IT firmware and it should serve you well.

That should be more than enough for home use, unless your home network is 10Gbps. :-)

I would not recommend Atoms -- the ones that support 64-bit mode and ECC memory do exist, but you're not very likely to find them in stores.